# Angular doesn't cancel a wrapped HTTP Request on Unsubscribing

Tags: angular, http, angular-http

> Update: Why can't you just use or return the built in `HttpClient`?
>   Because we have to intercept the response.

We have a `HttpService` which wraps the `HttpClient` provided by angular. It is used to apply headers/authorizations and do some operations on response *(... like Interceptors - we went this route because Interceptors weren't in Angular back then).*

> Our HttpService is very close to `HttpClient` and has similar methods
>   like `GET`, `POST`, etc. We will use `GET` as an example here.

I realized that while unsubscribing the methods, the `real HttpClient`
cancels the request while the `wrapped HttpService` **does not cancel
the request**. **[See this demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ti-http?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**So, my question is: How do I force the cancellation of the request on un-subscription? Or, is my implementation of the  `Observable.create` wrong (see below)?**

Below is an example on GET (Actual code does a lot more):

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    public get<T>(url: string): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            this.http.get<T>(url).subscribe(
                response =>  {
                     // some other things
                     observer.next(response);
                 },
                error =>  observer.error(error),
                () =>  observer.complete());
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Following is the network screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta, right but that doesn't give us the control over the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function passed to the create function should include the teardown logic. Notice how it is declared in [its docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create):

```
create(onSubscription: function(observer: Observer): TeardownLogic): Observable
```

The relevant piece is that [TeardownLogic](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~TeardownLogicDoc.html):

> Function that takes no parameters. When consumer of created Observable calls unsubscribe, that function will be called

So your code should look more like this:

```
public get<T>(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        let subs = this.http.get<T>(url).subscribe(
            response =>  {
                 // some other things
                 observer.next(response);
             },
            error =>  observer.error(error),
            () =>  observer.complete());

        return () => {
            // Your own tear down logic here and then:
            subs.unsubscribe();
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh, didn't even know about that. Thanks for opening my eyes. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

The httpclient returns an observable by default, so you do not need to create one. it will also cancel it automatically, as well. It should look like this:

```
public get<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(url).pipe(map(response => {
        // manipulate response here.

        return response;
    }));
}}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, we `intercept` the response. If we were to do that, we don't need the wrapper.

Comment: oops sorry, see response

Comment: This could definitely work, but the MondKin's answer was precisely what I was looking for thanks.